# Cypher query to exclude specific TLD's from node values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a single node containing domain names.

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n.name

"n.name"                  │
╞══════════════════════════╡
│""test01.bo-prod.htb""  │
├──────────────────────────┤
│""test01.bo-prod.local""│
├──────────────────────────┤
│""testa01.bo-prod.intra""│
├──────────────────────────┤
│""testa01.bo-prod.com""  │
├──────────────────────────┤
│""testa01.bo-prod.net""  │
└──────────────────────────┘
```

What is the most efficient way to RETURN only the domain names which are not local(exclude .intra, .local, .htb)?
I am trying to avoid using regular expression search for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a node label for that purpose then use the label when doing your query. For example:

1. Create the label, NonLocal

   ```
   WITH ['.intra', '.local', '.htb'] as excluded
   MATCH (n) WHERE not (any (x in excluded WHERE n.name contains x) )
   SET n:NonLocal
   ```
2. You query becomes

   ```
   MATCH (n:NonLocal)
   RETURN n
   ```

Reference: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/#set-set-a-label-on-a-node